# convert word to ascii and return to word adding some value

Tags: oracle, plsql, ascii

I am working on PL/SQL . The oracle password by developer is set such way

```
=> input word => converted to ascii => added 2 to each letter => converted back to word
```

ex: input password is "admin". 
admin is splitted into characters/letters (a, d, m, i, n)
converted to ascii and added 2 and again converted to word

```
a=97      97+2 = 99 = c
d=100     100+2=102 = f
m=109     109+2=111 = o
i=105     105+2=107 = k 
n=110     110+2=112 = p
```

what i did is

```
$pass=str_split('admin');

    foreach($pass as $password){
        $new_password[]=chr(ord($password)+2);
    }
$final= $new_password[0].$new_password[1].$new_password[2].$new_password[3].$new_password[4]; //the values 0-4 is set manually
echo $final;
```

result: ***cfokp***

But i could not get proper ans to run the result string on command and match the oracle password with the retrieved one.

Comment: If you want php solution why you have tagged this oracle plsql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way in **SQL** is to split the characters, add 2 to the ascii value, and aggregate the string.

Of course, it won't be faster than the TRANSLATE approach. But, for a single or small set of values it shouldn't matter much.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH data AS
  2    (SELECT 'admin' str FROM dual
  3    )
  4  SELECT str, LISTAGG(CHR(ASCII(REGEXP_SUBSTR(str, '\w', 1, LEVEL)) + 2), '') WITHIN GROUP(
  5  ORDER BY LEVEL) str_new
  6  FROM data
  7    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(str)
  8  /

STR    STR_NEW
------ -------
admin  cfokp

SQL>
```

The above **SQL** does following important tasks:

- Split the string into characters using **REGEXP_SUBSTR** and **ROW GENERATOR** technique
- Add value 2 to the ascii value of each character.
- Convert back the modified **ascii** into **characters**.
- Aggregate the string using **LISTAGG**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Lalit Kumar B, but can you please paste the php code where the user input password is 'admin' which matches the oracle password cfokp. I will really be grateful If you added a bit more favor

Comment: I see you have your PHP code with you(although I have no idea about PHP), I can assist you only with Oracle. So, you have both the parts, the PHP code to convert the password into that of Oracle's, and you also have the Oracle SQL. Now where do you find the gap? Do you need the PHP code to compare the two?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably easier to do with `translate`:

```
select translate('admin',
                 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',
                 'cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab'
                )
from dual;
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with "y" and "z".  This maps them back to "a" and "b".  You can extend this to upper case letters and other characters if you need.

Comment: sorry you didnt get what i mean. how can I convert word (either normal word or alpa numeric characters) to ascii and add 2 to each value and convert back it to word using php